# Internet Explorer 7+8 executes variable declaration inside IF even if condition is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, if-statement

The following JavaScript works correctly in all browsers except IE 7 and 8:

```
if (typeof django != 'undefined') {
    console.log('Django admin loaded');
    var jQuery = django.jQuery;
}
```

This code is on top of a JavaScript file that is loaded both inside Django's admin interface and on our public pages. Django's admin loads its own jQuery, so we use that one preferably ...

However, IE 7 and 8 executes the variable assignment inside this if statement even if the condition `(typeof django != 'undefined')` is `false`. At the same time, the `console.log()` is not executed :-/ Removing the `var` keyword, the same code works perfectly also in IE 7 and 8:

```
if (typeof django != 'undefined') {
    console.log('Django admin loaded');
    jQuery = django.jQuery;
}
```

But why? That doesn't make any sense, does it?

Comment: in which scope the code is executed... is it executed in the global scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*ALL browsers* will do this. It's called [*hoisting*](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-hoisting-explained--net-15092).

```
function test() {
    if( false) {
        var abc;
    }
    alert(abc); // expect ReferenceError, get undefined
}
```

Since you're defining `jQuery`, you *probably* want that as a global variable, so `window.jQuery = django.jQuery` should do just fine.

Comment: Thanks - great link with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as block scope within javascript (please see here for more details of JS scoping: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)).

Your initial code doesn't make much sense anyway - if you are trying to set the global jQuery variable, then your code should be:

```
if (typeof django != 'undefined') {
    console.log('Django admin loaded');
    jQuery = django.jQuery;
}
```

What you are seeing is probably a difference with how IE7 and 8 handle their JS scopes.

Comment: Possibly some further useful reading: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Answer (score 0):

If you define the var keyword then you need to do like this:

```
if (typeof django != 'undefined') {
    console.log('Django admin loaded');
    var jQuery = django;
    django.jQuery; // or django = django.jQuery
}
```